# How to find three largest numbers in an array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Hello I want to find the three largest numbers in an array by ORDER.
I am confused how I should implement the last logic where I have to shift the indexes of the result array based on if the the current number in the result array is greater or less than the loop of the array items.

```
    function findThreeLargestNumbers(array) {
  let result = [null, null, null];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!result[2] || result[i] > result[2]) {
      for (let j = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        if (j === 2) {
          result[j] = array[i]
        } else {
          result[j] = array[i + 1]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result
}


console.log(findThreeLargestNumbers([141, 1, 17, -7, -17, -27, 18, 541, 8, 7, 7]));
```

Comment: Odd logic to get to the answer.  Why not simply order the entire array, then output the top three results?

Comment: `result[i]` can't be correct. The index `i` relates to `array`, not `result`.

Comment: This is also obviously incorrect: `for (let j = 0; i <= 2; i++)`, mixing `i` and `j` in the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it in ascending order and use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the last `3` elements as:

**1)** When you want result in last 3 largest in ascending order `[18, 141, 541]`

```js
function findThreeLargestNumbers(array) {
  return [...array].sort((a, b) => a - b).slice(-3);
}

// [18, 141, 541]
console.log(findThreeLargestNumbers([141, 1, 17, -7, -17, -27, 18, 541, 8, 7, 7]));
```

**2)** When you want result in last 3 largest in descending order `[541, 141, 18]`

```js
function findThreeLargestNumbers(array) {
  return [...array].sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0, 3);
}

console.log(findThreeLargestNumbers([141, 1, 17, -7, -17, -27, 18, 541, 8, 7, 7]));
```

Comment: Even better to clone the array and get the last 3 number. BTW thanks EDITED

Comment: to clone the array would you use spread operator or for loop and push to empty array?

Comment: @dev `...` is not operator it is spread syntax. I'd go for `spread` syntax...